# Google AppEngine GAE ranking tree implementation transaction problems

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to implement player ranking built on a tree structure of Range objects with Rating objects attached to them on the lowest level of the tree. I know that there is a Java implementation (ported from Python) out there, but it uses the low-level datastore API and I'd like to do it using JPA. Here is the code snippet describing the structure:

```
@Entity
public class Range
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Range parent;
  // leaf node?
  private boolean leaf;
  // total number of rating objects in the node's subtree
  private long count;
  // child nodes
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Range> children;
  // range [max, min]
  private long max;
  private long min;

  @Version
  private int version;
}

@Entity
public class Rating
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;
  // parent range
  private Key range;
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Player player;
  // rating value
  private long value;

  @Version
  private int version;
}

@Entity
public class Player
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;
  // list of associated ratings for different game configurations (one per config)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Collection<Rating> ratings = new LinkedList<Rating>();

  @Version
  private int version;
}
```

Then there is a class representing the tree itself (Tree), which holds the root Range object (not shown here).
As you can see objects of class Range are actually the tree core, having one-to-many relationship between themselves. Player has one-to-many relationship with Rating objects (assuming there are few game types).
Here is an immediate issue, which can be solved: it would be nice to have one-to-many relationship between Range and Rating objects, but GAE does not support multiple parenting. Therefore, Ranges have a manually managed relationship with Ratings by holding parent range key in rating object. For the same reason Tree can not have managed one-to-one relationship with Range. It's also handled manually with the root node key stored in the tree object.
The real problem happens when inserting the first Rating into the tree, which didn't exist until now:

```
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

// start transaction
tx.begin();

// create the tree
Tree tree = new Tree();
em.persist(tree);
// and its root range
Range root = new Range();
em.persist(root);
// we need range key to attach it to the tree
em.flush();
// attach root range to the tree
tree.setRoot(root);
// save the tree
em.persist(tree);
em.flush();

// ...
// we have parent range (tree root), player and score
Rating rating = new Rating(); 
// one-to-many relationship: Player--<>Rating
player.getRatings().add(rating);
rating.setPlayer(player);
// attach to the parent range
rating.setParent(range);
rating.setValue(score);
// use entity manager to persist the new rating
em.persist(rating);

tx.commit();  <------------ here it fails
```

Below is the shortened exception dump:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction failed to commit
  at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:118)
  at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.commit(DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.java:58)
  ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Some instances failed to flush successfully due to optimistic verification problems.
  at org.datanucleus.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:271)
  at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:116)
  ... 39 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusOptimisticException: Optimistic concurrency exception updating ferp.center.server.entity.Range with pk Range(10).  The underlying entity had already been deleted.
  at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.newNucleusOptimisticException(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:391)
  at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.handleVersioningBeforeWrite(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:412)
  at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.updateObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:574)
  at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.flush(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:4576)
  at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2814)
  at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2754)
  at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2893)
  at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:369)
  at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:256)
  at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:104)
  ... 39 more
```

What am I doing wrong?